# How to print japanese text in PDF along with English characters using rghost?

Tags: ruby

I want to generate a PDF with English characters along with some Japanese characters also; using Rghost but unable to text. 
There is a ruby config file in Ruby 1.9.3, external encoding was ascii-8 bit, which i changed it to UTF-8 still no difference. 
The Japanese character is “アナンド” but while printing in PDF, its coming as      “ã¢ãã³ã”. What can be the probable solutions ?

Ruby version : 1.9.3
Rghost : 0.9.5
OS : Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Rghost does not ship with Japanese font by default.
If you have installed an external font, you can double check if it's installed properly by code below to generate catalog information
`RGhost::Config.environment_fonts.render :pdf, :filename => 'mycatalog.pdf'`

---

If you have not installed any external fonts, then you can do so by searching for *.ttf* fonts (External fonts such as TTF,PFA,PFB are supported font format).  Here's one such [link](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Japanese.html)
After downloading the file follow the steps below:

Step 1: Create a directory and copy the fonts to the created directory
`mkdir /temp/fontfolder`

Step 2: Create a file with filename `Fontmap`
Edit the file to include the following lines

```
/Japanesefont1 (aquafont.ttf);  
/Japanesefont2 (arialuni.ttf);
/Japanesefont3 (Cyberbit.ttf);
```

So that the file directory structure should look like

```
|-- temp
|   |-- fontfolder
|   |   |-- Japanesefont1
|   |   |-- Japanesefont2
|   |   |-- Japanesefont3
```

Step 4: Load the fonts
`RGhost::Config::GS[:extensions] << '/temp/fontfolder'`

Comment: I hav edited the questn pls hav a look. I hav loaded fonts like this- :extensions =>['C:\WATIR\IngeniumAutomationProject\Fonts\temp\fontfolder'] & defined the tags like this -                                                 d.define_tags do
    tag :myfont, :name => 'epgyobld', :from =>'C:\WATIR\IngeniumAutomationProject\Fonts\temp\fontfolder',  :size => 12
    end                                                                                            still no changes. I get characters like this-ã¢ãã³ã. fontfolder consists of japanese fonts and Fontmap folder